# Forcing all u+0061 to be u+0061(ss02)

Tags: fonts, document-body

I'm using Poppins font and I need to switch the a from the default to the variant. How can make that happen throughout my entire website? [visual of the glyphs with each code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pzaq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply CSS styling `font-feature-settings: "ss02" on;` to the content that needs the 'ss02' feature applied.

Comment: Thanks, I meant to take this down. It took some digging to find that. Also, I ran into the problem that google fonts doesn't include stylistic alternatives. So I had to use typekit to get the job done.